# CSS background image URL path

Tags: html, css, image, background

Hello Im trying to use background for my page using CSS.
The image is from another folder and I try to reference her to CSS file.

The CSS file URL is: /var/www/soFit/BO

The image file URL is: /var/www/soFit/BO/images/login

My CSS file:

```
#login-bg   
{

    background-image:url('/images/login/login_background.jpg');
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

My HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />

</head>

<body id="login-bg"> 

<form action="" method="POST">

Username:  <input type="text" name="username" > 
<br>
Password:  <input type="text" name="password" > 
<br>
<input type="submit" value="enter"> 

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Why I cant see my background image?

Comment: leading forward-slash is the issue.

Comment: Have you tried it without the leading slash? `background-image:url('images/login/login_background.jpg');`

Comment: For future reference if you look in the network inspector in the browsers developer tools you will be able to see the full path the browser is trying to read.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Remove the leading forward-slash from the image URL, as follows:

```css
#login-bg {
    background-image:url('images/login/login_background.jpg');
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

By using the leading forward-slash, browser tries to load the image from the web root directory of the domain (e.g `/var/www/`) instead of the current (CSS) file location.

Comment: You should probably explain _why_ it's the issue. The forward slash tells the browser to look for a directory at the same level as the current directory. Removing the forward slash tells the browser to look for a directory within the current directory for the file.

Comment: @KyleShevlin Absolutely, I was editing the post :) Thank you anyway.

Comment: @dasdasd Don't mention it :)

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
#login-bg   
{

    background-image:url('images/login/login_background.jpg');
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Using the slash '/' at the beginning of the route makes it an absolute route, not a relative route, which is what you want.

Comment: Technically the correct syntax would be a leading dot slash ` './images/login/login_background.jpg'`

Comment: @Misunderstood the dot to represent the current directory is a Unix thing. I'm not even sure that's part of the URI spec.

Comment: I stand corrected, it is indeed part of the URI spec. However, it's technically equivalent to having no leading slash, so it's not technically any more "correct", and in fact it's so obscure on the web I would recommend avoiding it.

Comment: @devios1 I don't remember making that comment or why. Probably because I ran into a case where not using the `./` did not work.  If you go by what is "on the web" that would be a bad idea. It's the blind leading the blind out there.  Technically I believe it is "more correct". But things change, I've been doing this stuff since the 70's.  For example I designed IBM's first Ethernet card for their PC. I always use the full qualified url `http://www.example.com/images/example.jpg`. The Browsers needs to use the full qualified url and by abbreviating it you give the Browser a little extra work.

Answer (score 1):

just write

```
background-image:url('images/login/login_background.jpg');
```

when you write /images it means images folder is coming from the root directory of the website. which in this case is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
background-image: url('../images/background.png');
```