# Cant load image with html. only works in css

Tags: html, css, webpack, vue.js

I have my css which contains a class

```
.Img{
  background: url('../assets/Trump.png');
}
```

And the html looks like this :

```
<div class="Img">
```

But when I want to have it like this

```
<div class="Img" style="background: url('../assets/Trump.png');">
```

the image won't load for me and I get an error

```
>GET http://localhost:8080/assets/Trump.png 404 (Not Found)
```

I am working with vue.js 2.0 and webpack

Comment: what is the **correct** path (location) of your image? (relatively to your `root` directory)

Comment: @Dekel background: url('../assets/Trump.png'); works great. So I think the path is correct. Its when I do it in the style tag it stops working

Comment: looks like it should be `url('assets/Trump.png')`

Comment: Think is not an answer to my question (And you already said that it works in the css). This is exactly why I asked **what** is the **correct** path.

Comment: what is the url of your html page? what is the path of the html file and the css file. Also how are you including the css file in your working html?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: @bansi, even though the values are missing I added a pretty explanatory answer :)

Comment: @KiffPowers, read the explanation in my answer

Comment: You know inline style attributes should be avoided anyway, right? Also use your browser's developer tools to check the path of the image when it is found and compare it to the 404 path

Answer (score 2):

The main issue here is relative paths.

If you have this structure for example:

```
/page.html
/static/
       /assets/
              /Trump.png
       /css/
           /file.css
```

And inside your `page.html` you have a `<link>` tag to your css (in `static/assets/css/file.css`), the call to `../assets/Trump.png` **from** that css file will get to the correct place (because from the `/css` directory - 1 directory up is the `static` directory, and from there we go inside the `assets` and everything is ok).

**However** - If we are inside the `/` directory (where the `page.html` exists), this is also our `root` directory, when we try to go to `../assets/Trump.png` the relative path we get is `/assets/Trump.png` (which does **not** exists in our server. The correct path should be `/static/assets/Trump.png`).

You should check the structure of your directories and put the correct relative path.

Comment: @Kiff Powers The point is in css file it is the `PATH` and in html it is `URL`, and you should understand they differ.

Comment: Both `path` and `url` are relative, and the question is relative to what/where. The image inside the `css` is relative to the path of the `css` file, and the image inside the `html` page is relative to the location of that `html` file.

Comment: @Dekel I've read it. And I work in vue components. So the css and html are in the same file. I think my issue is webpack related. Thanks for you help tho

Comment: Are you  sure the css and html are in the same file?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the apostrophes in the `url()`, `url()` function does not need them

```
<div class="Img" style="background: url(../assets/Trump.png);">
```

Comment: @BillCriswell Immediatly recognized ur name. See you a lot in the Vue gitter. Thanks for the link will check it out

Answer (score 0):

Edit your image url to this

```
<div class="Img" style="background-image: url('assets/Trump.png');">
```

when you are declaring this background-property in your css the url is correct the assets folder is in the parent directory of css. but when using inline css the assets and the html file are in the same directory that is why you are getting this error.

Comment: Still getting the error. Even tried it without the apostrophes.

Comment: is it loading via your css

Answer (score -1):

Check your image path, there's a chance that's the issue. Check this out: [CSS background image URL path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075730/css-background-image-url-path)

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to try some things. None of us know what your directory looks like, so until you're more specific, this is about as good as it gets for you.

Comment: What I meant was that this is not an answer to the question. It's a comment regarding how to solve the problem. You should wait till you have enough privileges to comment on questions.

Comment: And you do have enough reputation to contribute **answers**, but this is not an answer. You should read the FAQ of stackoverflow

Comment: This is an answer ;) I already did. You should probably review it though. This site is for HELPING others.

Comment: Good luck with that attitude here :) I hope for you that your user will not get ban.

Comment: You too buddy!!

Comment: @Joe Thanks for the help Joe! But I dont think the issue is the path